# Appium version is not displayed when it is installed from GitHub but displayed when installed via nodejs cmd. Should we install in both ways?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I'm new to Appium and started with setting up Appium desktop v 1.11.0 in my windows machine by downloading it from github .I downloaded NodeJS aswell and installed them. When i just navigate to cmd and typed "appium -v" I got the message as

**'appium' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

But however when i tried installing appium with "npm install -g appium" in the cmd appium is installed and appium version is displayed when typed "appium -v" as in below screenshot.

[appium version displayed after installing appium via cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Yuf.png)

Should we install appium from both cmd and github to work on Appium ?

But i feel like i missed some steps before checking for appium version in cmd after installing appium from github.

Please any one help me with correct installation of appium. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Appium server and Appium Desktop are not the same. The one you installed using npm command is appium server.

Appium Desktop is the combination of **Appium Server** and **Appium Inspector**. Using appium Desktop you can inspect the elements as well.

You can install both appium server and appium desktop as per your choice.